# Mode ~ mean in binomial distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

We toss a regular dice $60$ times. Denote $X$ the number of trials when the dice fell on one. The expected value of $X$ and the most probable value of $X$ are both equal to $10$, which is very intuitive. Is there some easy way to see that they are both equal (except calculating it)? In general is there some characterization of distributions that have this property?

Comment: Maybe one of the common characterization is a symmetric unimodal distribution which has mean = median = mode, provided that the mean exist.

Comment: @BGM Yes, in that case it is easy, but more interesting is when the distribution is asymmetric as in this case. In fact if you think about it there are a lot of ways how you can "make" an asymmetric distribution such that  the mean does not equal the mode, so the binomial distribution is a rare example of when the opposite holds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $X\simeq Bin(n,p)$, the mode is the largest integer $r$ satisfying the inequality $$\frac{n-r+1}{r}>\frac{1-p}{p}$$

in this case, since $p=\frac 16$, this rearranges as $$r<\frac{n+1}{6}$$
Meanwhile, $$E(X)=\frac n6$$

So if you throw the dice at least 6 times, and the number of times is a multiple of 6, then the mode will be the same as the expected value.

Comment: This is what I meant by calculating it.

Comment: Yes but the numbers tell the story. the mean is equal to the mode for particular numerical reasons.

Answer (score 3):

In general there is no specific relation as the most probable value is a local property of the distribution (only involving three values), while the expectation is a global one (involving all of them). Keeping the mode fixed, you can move the mean rather freely and the two values are pretty independent of each other. (More precisely, the mean can lie anywhere in $(\frac m2,\frac{n-m}2)$).

So I doubt that there is a better characterization than expressing that the mean and mode are equal.